# Websocket With Socket.io & Angular

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I want to create a websocket to add a communication between my angular app and my database. The app shall be able to save a question in a database & to notify the user when somebody answered.

Unfortunately I tried some tutorials which all don't work. I'm totally new to this because I use apache usually. So If you know a "working", very basic (beginner) tutorial, which doesn't require to install lots of additional things like yeoman etc. I would be glad.

In the current tutorial I get the error message:

```
You are trying to attach socket.io to an express request handler function. Please pass a http.Server instance.
```

My server.js:

```
var connect = require('connect'),
    serveStatic = require('serve-static'),
    socket = require('socket.io');

var server = connect();

server.use(serveStatic(__dirname+'/../client'));
server.listen(8080);
var io = socket.listen(server);
console.log("Server started and listen to http://127.0.0.1:8080");
```

without

```
var io = socket.listen(server);
```

it serves my static page.

---

This error is on my other approach:

```
has no method 'use'
```

My server.js

```
var connect = require('connect');
var http = require('http');
var serveStatic = require('serve-static');
var app = connect();
var server = http.createServer(app).use(serveStatic(__dirname+'/../client')).listen(3000);

var socket = require('socket.io');
var io = socket.listen(server);
```

Answer (score 1):

As always if you struggle long the solution comes quick after posting. That one works for the beginning:

```
var connect = require('connect');
var http = require('http');

var app = connect();

var fs = require('fs');
var index = fs.readFileSync(__dirname+'/../client/index.html');
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res){

        // Send HTML headers and message
        res.writeHead(200,{ 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
        res.end(index);
}).listen(3000);

var socket = require('socket.io');
var io = socket.listen(server);
```